# A Problem on Prime and Composite Numbers Relation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, pattern-recognition

I was fighting with this question for about five days and I’m unable to get a mathematical proof.

> *Question:* Let imagine a natural number and a prime number $q$ and $k$ respectively such that $k>q$ and $k$ is the nearest prime number with respect to $q$: 
>   $$             
>   f(n)= q n + k
>   \qquad
>   \text{where $n<k$}.
> $$
>   How can we calculate the number of values of $n$ so that $f(n)$ will always be a prime number for some values of $q$?

Example: let $q=4$, then the nearest prime number which is greater than $4$ is $5$, so $k=5$:
$$
  f(n) = 4n + 5,
  \qquad
  \text{here $n<5$}.
$$
If $n$ is $2$ and $3$ then $f(n)$ are prime numbers, so the total values of $n$ are $2$.

Similarly for $q = 6$ then $k = 7$:
$$
  f(n) = 6n + 7,
  \qquad
  \text{here $n<7$}.
$$

If $n$ is $1$,$2$,$4$,$5$ and $6$ then $f(n)$ are primes. So the total number of values of $n$ are $5$ which satisfy our conditions.

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Which parameters are set?  if $k,q$ are set then obviously $f(n)$ isn't always prime.

Comment: Exactly. there are no values that satisfy this

Comment: i mention the example please check it

Comment: The edit doesn't really help.  Maybe you are trying to ask something like "if $p$ is a prime and $m$ is any integer not divisible by $p$, can we always find an integer $n$ such that $pn+m$ is prime?"  That is indeed the case, and easily follows from the main result in [Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: no i am asking the a general formulas to calculate the possible values of "n" for any natural number which satisfy the conditions

Comment: Please edit your post to ask a coherent question.  You only ask about the number of such $n$ which, following Dirichlet, is infinite.  There is no known general formula that produces primes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is more comment than answer, so I'm making it Community Wiki in case anyone wants to extend or correct the sequence.

The question defines a function

$$P(q)=\#\{n\mid1\le n\lt k\text{ and }nq+k\text{ is prime, where }k\text{ is prime and }\pi(k)-\pi(q)=1\}$$

(Note, $\pi(k)-\pi(q)=1$ is a way of saying that $k$ is the *first* prime greater than $q$.) For example,

$$P(6)=\#\{n\mid1\le n\lt k\text{ and }6n+7\text{ is prime}\}=\#\{1,2,4,5,6\}=5$$

since $13$, $19$, $31$, $37$, and $43$ are prime but $25$ is not. Similarly we have

$$P(1)=1,\quad P(2)=2,\quad P(3)=2,\quad P(4)=2,\quad P(5)=2,\\\quad P(7)=2,\quad P(8)=5,\quad P(9)=4,\quad P(10)=5$$

so we have a sequence beginning

$$1,2,2,2,2,5,2,5,4,5,\ldots$$

The OEIS does not (yet) recognize this sequence, even without the initial $1$. (Caveat: I've done all the arithmetic and counting in my head, so I wouldn't mind if someone doublechecked the sequence.) This doesn't prove anything, of course, but it suggests there's no simple relation that describes the sequence.